Form submission doesn't go through (gets blocked by spring security)
I am trying to save user details in database spring jpa hibernate. But cannot save.
Here is the Security Config Class
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http 
             .csrf((csrf) -> csrf 
              .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()))
             .csrf((csrf) -> csrf   
              .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))  
                
                
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/signup", 
                        "buyer/buyer-registration", 
                        "buyer/buyer-reg-success", "buyer/buyer-reg-error", "/registration-error").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/edit", "/delete").authenticated()    
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")     
                .permitAll())
            .logout((logout) -> logout 
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                                .permitAll())
                
            
                 .sessionManagement((session) -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                
            
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); 
        


Here is the Thymeleaf HTML codes.
The Security Config and the Thymeleaf codes
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Buyer Registration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Buyer Registration</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/buyer/registerNewBuyer}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
        <label for="buyerUserName">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="buyerUserName" th:field="*{buyerUserName}" required/><br/>

        <label for="f_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="f_name" th:field="*{f_name}" required/><br/>

        <label for="l_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="l_name" th:field="*{l_name}" required/><br/>

        <h2>Location</h2>
        <label for="kindred">Kindred:</label>
        <input type="text" id="kindred" th:field="*{buyerLocation.kindred}" required/><br/>

        <label for="village">Village:</label>
        <input type="text" id="village" th:field="*{buyerLocation.village}" required/><br/>

        <label for="community">Community:</label>
        <input type="text" id="community" th:field="*{buyerLocation.community}" required/><br/>

        <label for="l_g_a">LGA:</label>
        <input type="text" id="l_g_a" th:field="*{buyerLocation.l_g_a}" required/><br/>

        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" th:field="*{buyerLocation.state}" required/><br/>

        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <input type="text" id="country" th:field="*{buyerLocation.country}" required/><br/>

        <h2>Google Location</h2>
        <label for="google_coordinates">Google Coordinates:</label>
        <input type="text" id="google_coordinates" th:field="*{buyerGoogleLocation.google_coordinates}" required/><br/>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


Below is the logs
2024-06-20 07:16:00 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
2024-06-20 07:16:00 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1555152978<open>)]
2024-06-20 07:16:00 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1555152978<open>)] after transaction
2024-06-20 07:16:00 DEBUG o.s.s.j.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository - Cleaned up 0 expired sessions
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /buyer/registerNewBuyer
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /login
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /login
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.marketgb.productgb.AuthenticationController#login(Model)
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.u.f.SpringTemplateLoader - Looking for FreeMarker template with name [login_en_US.ftlh]
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.u.f.SpringTemplateLoader - Looking for FreeMarker template with name [login_en.ftlh]
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.u.f.SpringTemplateLoader - Looking for FreeMarker template with name [login.ftlh]
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry - Function 'favicon.ico' is not found in cache
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry - Function 'favicon.ico' is not available in FunctionCatalog or BeanFactory
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry - Function 'favicon.ico' is not found in cache
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry - Function 'favicon.ico' is not found in cache
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry - Function 'favicon.ico' is not available in FunctionCatalog or BeanFactory
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry - Function 'favicon.ico' is not found in cache
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /favicon.ico
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /login
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /login
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.marketgb.productgb.AuthenticationController#login(Model)
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Selected '*/*' given [image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, image/svg+xml, image/*, */*;q=0.8]
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
2024-06-20 07:16:06 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.S.SESSION_LOGGER - No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2024-06-20 07:17:00 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2024-06-20 07:17:00 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(874249822<open>)] for JPA transaction
2024-06-20 07:17:00 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2b52e6c4]
2024-06-20 07:17:00 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
2024-06-20 07:17:00 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION
WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?

I have adjusted my security config call to permit all registration endpoints. I have adjusted my thmeleaf to good. But yet cannot save to database

Where is the code that is supposed to save the user? How do you know it has been triggered? Is there an error message (cause if not chance are your code hasn't been triggered)

That log doesn't tell us much. As J Asgarov stated we need to see the code and ideally an exception stack trace. Did you step through your code with a debugger already? What were your findings? The log you posted doesn't tell us much: you seem to have accessed the "/login" url which by using a GET might indicate you'
re just displaying the page. Then there a bunch of session cache misses (those are ok) and a single delete statement being executed.

Hello @JAsgarov, I have added the code that is supposed to save the user. Please I need your feedback.

Hello @Thomas, I have added the code that is supposed to save the user. Please I need your feedback.

you would have to show us also the buyerService.addNewBuyer method AS WELL AS the request you are sending... What request have you tried sending and what response have you got back?

Hello @JAsgarov, thanks so far for your answers. Meanwhile I have added the buyerSevice.addNewBuyer. There is an If condition that checks if a buyer Username exists before it saves to the repository. Do you need more information? Do you need me to provide the Thymeleaf html?

Did you see that Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login that's logged after Securing POST /buyer/registerNewBuyer? That indicates your request didn't send valid credentials or token so the system decided to redirect to the login page first. We'd need more info on how you set up security and how you're doing the call.

Hello @Thomas , I have added the Security Config. And I have also added the Thymeleaf HTML call. Can you check it out?

Hello @JAsgarov , I have added the Security Config. And I have also added the Thymeleaf HTML call. Can you check it out?

buyer/buyer-registration is not the same as /buyer/buyer-registration. Your spring security configuration has permitted buyer/buyer-registration whereas the actual request begins with /.
For all the requests that don't match specified paths, you have defined that they have to be authenticated
...
.anyRequest().authenticated())`

therefore you get redirected to /login
Update your security config as follows:
...
.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
     .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/signup", 
           "/buyer/buyer-registration", 
           "/buyer/buyer-reg-success", "buyer/buyer-reg-error", 
           "/registration-error").permitAll()
...


Hello @J Asgarov, Thanks, I will make corrections
